# Opening a PDF File by script, printing it, and closing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

A friend of mine got some PDF files infected with malware. He figured out that if he opens them on Ubuntu and prints them back to a file it removes the malware.

Anyone know if there is a way to script the opening, printing, and closing of a directory of PDF files?

Comment: It's being opened in an Ubuntu virtual machine that's locked off from the network.  No other method works for removing the malware.

Comment: As long as it's isolated. If this is done casually there could be consequences.

Comment: PDF files are just text. Have you tried editing the file at that level to identify the issue? Is this with previously harmless PDFs that got corrupted by some kind of malware?

Comment: Yes - Most of the characters in the PDF are unrecognizable, thus it's impossible to distinguish the malware from the characters that are part of the PDF.  It's Ransom Ware so on Windows the PDFs won't even open, but Ubuntu can open them, so by putting them through a print to file process he's able to remove the malware / ransom ware characters so that the file opens on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it. I suggest you take a look at [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

A sample script could look like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
let page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(link_to_pdf_file, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
try {
    await page.pdf({
        path: path_to_save_result_pdf,
        format: 'letter',
        Landscape: true,
        scale: 1,
        printBackground: true,
        margin: {
            top: '95px',
            bottom: '95px',
            left: '95px',
            right: '95px'
        }
    })

    consoleLog('Page saved: ' + p.url);
} catch (e) {
    consoleLog(`Save pdf error: ${e}`)
}
await browser.close();
```

Unfortunately I do not have a chance to check if this is working at the moment. It might require some minor changes, this was taken from my working project though.

Comment: While well intentioned, this code is really pointless as this doesn't solve the problem, just works around it.